# "Siri, set the timer for X minutes"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Every time I ask Siri to

> set **the timer** for X minutes

I get corrected with

> set **a timer** for X minutes

I consulted some tech sites, they seem to agree on "a timer". At least, I didn't find any "the timer" questions.

> Hey Siri, start **a timer** for 15 minutes.
>
> Say something like "Set **a timer** for 20 minutes."

I don't understand why, though.

I've got a phone (**my phone**, **the phone** I am possessing), I've installed some software on it (**the applications** I find handy and use on a daily basis), there are some pre-installed programs running on it (**the applications** provided out of the box). Being perfectly aware of **the timer feature**, I am asking Siri to launch it. To launch **the timer**, not **a timer**. To set **the timer**, not **a timer.**

Where am I wrong?

Feel free to correct any mistakes. I'd be utterly grateful if you cleared up my confusion.

---

UPDATE:

Yes, I understand that other words (including articles) around "timer" and "X minutes" don't play a big role, and they won't even be taken into consideration after parsing the keywords.

But corrections/replies from Siri like

> Setting **a timer** for X minutes...
>
> **A timer** is already running.

bring ambiguity and are totally confusing to me.

I am absolutely sure my iPhone is well aware of the processes it initiated (the applications it ran) X minutes ago.

> **The timer** (from the Clock app/the one I can run) is already running.
>
> Setting **the timer** (the timer installed in the Clock program/the one I have access to/the one I can set).

Comment: Well, you’re not wrong.  The iPhone only has one timer.   “Set the timer” is perfectly right.    Set “a timer” is more abstract.  The iPhone will set “a timer” — the only one it has.  Either one is correct.

Comment: By using  the keyword 'timer' you  make Siri use the Clock app, which has only one timer, but if you instead say 'Remind me [something] in ten minutes' you use the Reminders app, which can have any number of times events.

Comment: @whiskeychief please, see my update. I agree that "a timer" is more abstract and my phone will be able to figure out what timer to run (the only one it actually can run). But what about replies like "A timer is already running"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey please, see my update. I didn't catch the analogy with reminders but I had no problem with them.

Comment: From a grammar standpoint, I think you are right, it’s “the timer” and “the timer is already running.”

Comment: You could say *set the **timer app** for 5 minutes*, but you're not. In this case, *timer* is being used in the same way as *a countdown*, *an event*, *a reminder*, or *a calendar entry*. It's something *new* that's being created each time, not something preexisting. No doubt Siri can create *multiple* timers too. So, you're talking about one of many. So, you would set *one* timer for 5 minutes, and *another* timer for 20 minutes, for instance. It's describing something virtual.

Comment: @JasonBassford The problem is Siri can't create multiple timers. "**A** timer is already running. Would you like to replace it?"

Comment: Siri _can_ create multiple timers. They are called 'reminders'. There is no difference between saying 'set a timer for 10 minutes' and 'remind me to respond to Timer One in fifteen minutes' except that you can do the latter multiple times. They are both ways of accessing the operating system's time measurement ability.

Comment: If only one so-called timer can be created, I'd call that a deficiency in the software, not in the language that's being used. If you had a physical device that *only* acted as a timer (the famous *egg timer* for instance), and which was either off or currently counting down its one and only set time, then *the* timer would make sense. But I see nothing wrong with *a* timer in this context—even if the software has some kind of limitation built into it.

Comment: @JasonBassford You've got nice thoughts on this. If you added an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

> set **the timer** for X minutes

you know what timer you are talking about. But from the point of view of Siri, it is not very clear what you have in mind.

First, the device already uses a lot of timers which you know nothing about. They are set, reset, incremented, decremented, stopped all the time, without your knowledge.

Second, timers can be implemented by several programs. It is even possible that every (or some) programs are able to set more than 1 timer.

Therefore, it is much better to talk "generically" and use "a timer":

> set **a timer** for X minutes

Comment: if "the timer" is not very clear for Siri, how could "a timer" be clearer?

Comment: I think "generically" is better, I edited.

Comment: "a timer" gives Siri a chance to find the best solution for your need. It will assume that you need a generic timer for your personal purpose, and that decision is what you most likely want. If you use "the", then Siri has many alternatives, of which only one is correct - but it cannot decide which one.

Comment: Then "a timer" should raise questions about "which timer/which application to run", but it doesn't.

Comment: There is some default application for timing purposes, providing features such as alarm, countdowns, timers... Siri will use that. If there is no default such application, Siri will probably ask you to choose one.